# Clear the filter of a particular column

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

How to clear the filter of a particular column using excel vba

filename is wsCopy,
Column field is 100

Comment: Record a macro while doing that, and look at the generated code.  That would be a good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

If you want, you can specify filename and sheet name, or  don't. In the shorter version, make sure to have the right sheet activated (clicked on):

```
'longer
Workbooks("wsCopy").Sheets([sheet_name]).Range([col:col]).AutoFilter Field:=100
        
'shorter - activate the right sheet
Range([col:col]).AutoFilter Field:=100
```

remember to fill in `[sheet_name]` and `[col:col]` - refering to columns with autofilter.

#### Example

I will use a smaller Range for simplicity. 
Filter is applied to columns **B:E** and I wish to remove it from column **D = 3**rd column (counting from B).

I will assume the sheet is called "Data". Then the following code can be used:

```
'longer
Workbooks("wsCopy").Sheets("Data").Range("B:E").AutoFilter Field:=3

'shorter
Range("B:E").AutoFilter Field:=3
```

[image: example of data with filter applied in column C]